# Start Mongo with a flag

Tags: mongodb

Is it possible to start `mongod` (using systemctl) with `--master` flag?

I want to use the `oplog` file to watch for data changes. I know this should be used with replicas set, but on my development machine I don't need any replicas set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is an option to enable oplog on standalone mongod. All you need to do is start mongod with `--master` option. Or if you have a config file add the entry `master=true`.
This option will ensure that oplog will be created, but unlike a replica set there will not be any secondary instances of mongod which will read it and apply it to their local databases.